# How to show an AlertDialog juste after a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I searched across the web but I didn't find any satisfying answer.

I have a task that can make some time to complete so I use a ProgressDialog to inform the user that the application is doing something.

If an error is encountred during the long task, I want to display an AlertDialog to let the user know about the error.

So I wrote the code but the ProgressDialog dismisses and the AlertDialog doesn't show.

I use the onCreateDialog() method to manage my dialogs.

Someone knows why?

Thank you.

Comment: The code that manage the dialogs : http://snipplr.com/view/50650/dialog-managing/

Comment: The code that call the dialogs http://snipplr.com/view/50651/displaying-the-dialogs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but if it's a timing issue you might try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to call show your second dialog after a short delay:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showDialog(ERROR_CREDENTIALS_DIALOG);
    }
});
```

This may give the UI thread some time to clean up the first dialog, whose presence may be affecting the second. You might also try `postDelayed` instead with a small time delay such as 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I keep you posted.

Comment: I tried your code even with postDelayed with 10000ms and replacing showDialog() by MyActivity.this.showDialog(). Still nothing appears on the screen =S

Comment: I have the following warning but I don't know if it is related to my problem : WARN/InputManagerService(42): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4066c660

Comment: I've put a Log.d statement in the run() method and I never see it.

Comment: can you show the second dialog without the first one as a sanity check?

Comment: Finally, I managed to do it by putting the Handler into a class field. I don't really know why it worked... Thank you for your help!

Comment: the handler might have been getting garbage collected, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to show alert Dialog .

```
    public void OpenDialog()
    { 
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          dialog.setTitle("Error");
          dialog.setTitle("Your Message");

            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int buttons) 
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int buttons) 
        {
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know of to display a Dialog but the problem is that I can't manage to show a dialog just after I had dismissed one. =(

Comment: I did in the comment of my first post ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the progress dialog is fully dismissed before opening the alert dialog. I use the cancel method for that.

---

progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);

...

public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {
   showAlertDialog();
}

...

progressDialog.cancel()

---

Once you task is complete you will call progressDialog.cancel();
This will trigger the onCancel method and open the alert dialog showing nicely both alert out and in animations.

Note: you can also use dismiss() for this, but it's a bit more error prone.